# Store content of .load html file in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

On button click, i am appending a `tfoot` to a `table`. The contents of the `tfoot` is the result of a `.load` to a local .html file. Although my solution works, i am performing a get to the .html file on every click. Can the result on first click be stored in a variable, and reused?

```
$scope.btnClick = function() {

    var tfoot = $('#datepicker table').find('tfoot');
    if(!tfoot.length) {
        tfoot = $('<tfoot>').appendTo('#datepicker table');
    }

    tfoot.load('myDir/calendar/customFooter.html');

}
```

Comment: and use it as a global var you mean?

Comment: create a data store or a variable or even stor in local storage. Too many options available. people use them a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a callback on the `load()` method to store the result. I use your `$scope` variable for this, but you can amend this as needed. Try this:

```
$scope.btnClick = function() {    
    var tfoot = $('#datepicker table').find('tfoot');
    if (!tfoot.length) {
        tfoot = $('<tfoot>').appendTo('#datepicker table');
    }

    if ($scope.tfootContent) {
        tfoot.html($scope.tfootContent);
    } else {
        tfoot.load('myDir/calendar/customFooter.html', function(response) {
            $scope.tfootContent = response;
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `tfoot.html(scope.tfootContent)` => `tfoot.html($scope.tfootContent);` - `$` missed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the templateCache for this, (see reference here -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) I believe that would be a better approach. That way you don't need to do additional work and it will get cached. You'd show the tfoot on button click so it would be something like this:

```
$scope.btnClick = function() { tfootVisible = true;}
```

and in the html

```
<table id="datepicker">
   <tfoot ng-include="'templateId.html'" ng-if="tfootVisible"></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting. I would still need to inject the tfoot on click as this isnt part of the out of box datepicker html

Comment: @Oam Try to have all the html manipulation in html, and avoid jquery appending as much as possible in the controllers. Since you're coding the view just include and make it not visible at the beginning using ng-if. If you don't have to use that datepicker you can check the datepicker from here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (datepicker popup)